# How do I find a replacement fan for an IBM T40?

Tags: laptop, fan

The fan in my IBM T40 has died. I have taken the laptop apart and I see that it no longer spins. It kinda whirs for a bit and then stops.

I've found some replacement fans on E-Bay for $10. What should I look for to make sure my T40 will be compatible with what I purchase on E Bay?

Note: The T40 is at least 7 years old, so no more warranty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a link to the [T40 Hardware Manual](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?lndocid=MIGR-46464).  Inside you will find the FRU number for the fan assembly of your model.

However, buying a fan just by model number will work too.  The #1 thing to look (and even ask the vendor) for, is if the fan is 'brand new' or refurbished.  With refurbished ones, you have a higher chance of getting an Original IBM fan, but they have some wear an tear and will probably be noisy.  A brand new one will very likely be an OEM one.

(I have recently bought one for a T30 model.  It was an OEM one and even more effective than the original IBM fan)

EDIT: Here is an even better link:  [FRU Numbers for T40-series](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?sitestyle=lenovo&lndocid=MIGR-46474) (see pt. 18)

Comment: awesome. time to 'breath' some life into this 7yr old laptop

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do is simply ask the seller.

Also, you may want to check spare part companies for your laptop model and find the exact model number - you can then search via that part number either on eBay or from other spare parts companies and guarantee a compatible match.

Comment: Can't ask the seller - Old laptop

Answer (score 1):

Check the Lenovo (IBM) part number to make sure the fan is correct. The FRU number will help you find the exact part.

[Lenovo T Series parts](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/MIGR-46474.html)